# airport -s command to return wifi network info sometimes returns nothing

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I am relying on `airport -s` called from an application to return information about the available wifi networks. However, sometimes it immediately returns without providing any information. I've also experienced this when running it directly on the command line.

Anyone know why that is happening and what I can do about it?

Comment: If your wi-fi is off, it'll return nothing. Are you sure that's not what's happening?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I do nothing to the wifi, it's on. Last time I tried, I just ran the command 3 times. First 2 times, it returned nothing, 3rd time it returned the data. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Weird. No idea then.